# How to introduce .h file when writing LoadRunner script in C language?

Tags: loadrunner

How to introduce.h files when writing LR scripts in C language.
The. H file has been moved to the script path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this header file to be local in scope, for this virtual user process and application?   Or, do you want it to be global in scope, crossing virtual users, apps, processes?

What have you tried?   What has not worked and what have you learned from the failures?

If this a .h file of your own design or a third party component that you are looking to integrate with LoadRunner?